# OpenGL Draw Image. PIC Library

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glut

I'm trying to draw an image on the screen. I'm using the PIC library for images.

Right now, I have an array of pixel intensities, where each value looks like this

```
currentImage->pix[currentRow * x * bytesPerPixel] = number from 0 to 256.
```

I'm trying to draw out the image using something like this:

```
// initialize the most basic image
for (int y = currentImage->ny; y >= 0; y--) {

    // draw out each row of pixels
            // line 18 -- this following line throws the error on compile
            glReadPixels(0, 479-y, 640, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &image->pix[y*image->nx*image->bpp]);

}
```

But this doesn't work. When I attempt to compile, I keep getting this error:

```
g++ -O3 -I/usr/local/src/pic -Iinclude -o current src/main.cpp src/modules/*.cpp -L/usr/local/src/pic -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -lpicio -ljpeg
src/modules/application.cpp: In function ‘void application::idle()’:
src/modules/application.cpp:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const GLvoid*’
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Has anyone had a similar issue before? I'm just attempting to draw the most basic image on the screen to start with for now.

Here's my main.cpp function where I initialize the the gl display function.

```
 // set up the main display function
  glutDisplayFunc(application::display);

  // set the various callbacks for the interaction with opengl
  glutIdleFunc(application::display);
```

Application.cpp full file:

```
namespace application {

    void init() {


        idle();     
    }

    // implement idle function -- responsible for working with the image on a consistent basis to continually ensure its integrity
    void idle() {

        // initialize the most basic image
        for (int y = currentImage->ny; y >= 0; y--) {

            // draw out each row of pixels
            glDrawPixels(currentImage->nx, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, currentImage->pix[y * currentImage->nx * currentImage->bpp]);  
        }

    }   


    // display is for drawing out the elements using our scaled frame etc
    void display() {

        // rotate, scaling and translation should take place before this code in the future
        // draw a quick cube around the origin of the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
        glClearColor(000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glutSwapBuffers();

    }

}
```

Comment: What does `application.cpp` have around line 18?

Comment: This is an isolated function. I initialize my program and draw the background etc before this function.

Comment: It's stopping your program from compiling though. Can you show us application.cpp, or least  a section of it around line 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is your problem is here:

```
glDrawPixels(currentImage->nx, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, currentImage->pix[y * currentImage->nx * currentImage->bpp]);
```

The last argument of glDrawPixels needs to be const GLVoid*

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml

But you're passing it an int.

Comment: Any ideas how I could convert the integer to the proper value for this? I was looking through that link and other pieces of documentation for the drawing and couldn't seem to get anything going

Comment: I've never actually used glReadPixels or glDrawPixels before. But the argument const GLVoid* is labeled data. So I'm taking a guess that this should be a pointer to your data buffer. So try passing it just currentImage->pix Or if the data is at an offset the use &currentImage->pix[offsetAmount]